# How to get non-numeric entries in a column of a database

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have customer database that we use for auto-charges.  It would appear that the CC expiration field has a couple records with invalid entries for expiration date... for example non-numeric.  Is there a way to search for entries with a NON-Numeric value? Below is the start of how I would assume the query would look...

```
select *
from customers
where ccexperiation = non numeric
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
select *
from customers
where ISNUMERIC(ccexperiation) = 0
```

With some minor caveats.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186272.aspx).

Comment: Thanks.  That also returned all records without an expiration date (typically non active).  Is there a way to search for records that have something in the field besides numeric, excluding the records if they are Blank, or Numeric?

Comment: Just add `AND ISNULL(ccexperiation, '') <> ''` to the end of the query to exclude blanks (and NULLs).